# Yii2 disable highlighting menu item

Tags: menu, widget, yii2

My main.php code

```
<?php
        NavBar::begin([
            'brandLabel' => 'Styl-dekoracje.pl',
            'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
            'options' => [
                'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
            ],
        ]);
        echo Nav::widget([
            'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                ['label' => 'Orders', 'url' => ['/order']],
                Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
                    ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']] :
                    ['label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                        'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                        'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']],
            ],
        ]);
        NavBar::end();
    ?>
```

When I click for login/logout or home item its will be highlight. But how can I disable highlighting for `SiteController`? Where is file who set item as active?

Comment: Where exactly you want disable highlighting? And under what conditions?

Answer (score 4):

Each item insive `Nav` have `active` property.

Set it depending on current controller, action, or route.

Example:

```
[
    'label' => 'Login', 
    'url' => ['/site/login'],
    'active' => $this->context->route == 'site/login',
],
```

Setting this for `site/logout` doesn't make sense because it's immediate action with redirect.

**Official documentation:**

- [Nav $items](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html#$items-detail)
- [View $context](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$context-detail)
- [Controller $route](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#$route-detail)

Comment: This should be in the documentation as an example, I've been searching for  this for a while, it's especially useful for the localized navbars.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Yii2, but in Yii there was an **activeCssClass** option.

```
'activeCssClass' => ''
```

The code above disbaled the higlighting of active menu item.

Comment: The question is about Yii2, not Yii1.

Comment: Yes, but in Yii2 should be something similar. Take a look on the API

Comment: @DanielGonsalesKasas no it's not. Comparing yii2 with yii1 is like comparing an apple with an orange ;)

Comment: @noc2spam ツ, offtopic question. I got a project on Yii, but after reading the upgrade guide I decided no to do so.  Is it worth upgrading from 1.X to 2.0?

Comment: @DanielGonsalesKasas it is totally worth doing that. Yii2.0.x is 10 times better than Yii 1.1.x. Yii now uses Namespaces. Installation is maintained by composer. RBAC is much better implemented using `yii2-admin` extension. A lot of changes have been made in `DAO`. You can have a frontend, an api, a backend application all in one codebase. Community support has always been excellent, so nothing changed on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Url::to()` to make it work. This is just a workaround.

```
<?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'Styl-dekoracje.pl',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
    ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => Url::to(['/site/index'])],
            ['label' => 'Orders', 'url' => Url::to(['/order'])],
            Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
                ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => Url::to(['/site/login'])] :
                ['label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                    'url' => Url::to(['/site/logout']),
                    'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']],
        ],
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
?>
```

Comment: `url` already will be processed by `Url::to()`, how it's related with activity by the way?

Comment: @arogachev I don't really know. But it doesn't highlights the links when it is used.