# Unable to Highlight/activate menu bar items for static page urls in yii2

Tags: yii2, navbar

I am using basic Yii2 App. I am using the Nav Bar widget and having problem in highlighting current menu item. My problem the Nav bar items are not getting activated when they have static pages in their url value. for e.g  When `domain_name/site/contact` is clicked it highlights the nav bar item "Contact Us" as it's calling a controller action whereas when I am rendering static pages and using URL as `domain_name/site/page?view=about/about_us`, the parent Item "About" and Child Item "About Us" is not getting highlighted/activated. Can't find a possible solution to it.

The code I used is given below

```php
[
     'label' => 'About',
     'items' => [
         ['label' => 'About College', 'url' => ['/site/page?view=about/about_us']],                                           
     ],
],
```

and for Contact us

```php
['label' => 'Contact Us', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii2 disable highlighting menu item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914285/yii2-disable-highlighting-menu-item)

Comment: Sorry to say @arogachev ...I have already seen that question and that's not what I am asking. I have solved it.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can post this solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following workaround , in the nav widget I have used

```php
    'activateItems'=>'true',
    'activateParents'=>'true',
```

and for items

```php
    ['label' => 'About',
                 'items'=>[
                    ['label' => 'About College', 'url' => ['/site/page?view=about/about_us'],'active'=>Yii::$app->request->getUrl() == Url::toRoute(['/site/page?view=about/about_us'])],],],
```

Comment: So why mentioned answer is "not what you are asking"? You need to use `active` property and customize check to fit your needs. Also I don't recommend to check current url that way.

Comment: @arogachev ...it will be really helpful if u can suggest a possible solution. Thanks in advance